# Разметка HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Розовый фон - блок с шириной `1180px`. Размером остальных элементов можно пренебречь.
Мой код тут: http://jsfiddle.net/w76ohy8v/

Проблема: не удается сместить `.youtube-button` под `.wrapper`, как показано на макете, который прикреплен к данному вопросу.

Comment: **Непонятна суть вопроса**. 
Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное выравнивание с помощью flex.

```css
.left-statistic {
    width: max-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffcc66;
}
.left-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.statistic-block {
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    width: 18em;
    height: 13em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.statistic-block-text {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.count-sub {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 position:relative;
}
.youtube-button img {
    width: 500px;
}
.youtube-button {
    margin-bottom: 700px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    width: 36em;
    height: 10em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-statistic">
  <div class="left-block">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="statistic-block"><span class="count-sub">13.4M</span><br> <span
              class="statistic-block-text">Подписчиков</span></div>
      <div class="statistic-block"><span class="count-sub">2.4B</span><br> <span
              class="statistic-block-text">Просмотров</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="youtube-button"><img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png"
            alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <iframe width="575px" height="400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nHdO26B9qjw" frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Всего лишь левый блок нужно было помести в отдельный `div` ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️. Спасибо!